# How can I get Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT as a result, if I use different fields from different entities in a select clause

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('C')
            ->select('C.id, C.name, P.id, P.name')
            ->leftJoin('C.Product', 'P')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

Above query returns HYDRATE_ARRAY, and I want HYDRATE_OBJECT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use any mysql function like group_concat and get ids

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('C')
            ->select('C, GROUP_CONCAT(C.id) AS ids, partial P.{id, name}')
            ->leftJoin('C.Product', 'P')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

foreach($query as $q) {
   echo $q[0]->getId().' -- '.$q[0]->getProduct()->getId().' -- '.$q['ids'];
}
```

Here you can get all field of category table, group ids of category table and product table filed

Thanks

Ashok Chitroda

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('C')
            ->select('partial C.{id, name}, partial P.{id, name}')
            ->leftJoin('C.Product', 'P')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

your can get result

```
foreach($query as $q) {
   echo $q->getId().' -- '.$q->getProduct()->getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it.

```
/**
 * return all devices enabled to array
 *
 * @return array
 */
private function getAllDevicesToArray()
{
    // return to array not object
    return $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AdminBundle:Device')
        ->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->where('d.enabled = :enabled')
        ->setParameter('enabled', 1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
}
```